# SQL Query for Events table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `event` table in Postgres, with this structure:

```
event
--------
id: serial, pk
item_id: text, fk
status: text, an enum such as CREATED, IN_PROGRESS, DONE...
```

This works as a log, so all entries are immutable, change is status will be another INSERT.

I want to efficiently extract all events which have status CREATED, but not DONE.

Comment: How do you define "event"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want ITEMs that meet the conditions.  If so:

```
select item_id
from events
where status in ('CREATED', 'DONE')
group by item_id
having max(status) = 'CREATED';
```

This uses the fact that `'CREATED' < 'DONE'` alphabetically.  You can also use conditional aggregation:

```
having count(*) filter (where status = 'DONE') = 0;
```

Comment: was in a similar direction, but with `string_agg`, but better ask the SQL experts :) Which one do you recommend more?